# How to iterate in reverse from the middle of a text file?

Tags: python, json, loops, text

**The Problem**:
I am writing a program whose ultimate objective is to extract several specific lines from text-versions of .json files. I want to automate the manual process of copy/pasting tens or hundreds of lines  that all share the same keyword, but of which are a few lines removed FROM that keyword.

**Proposed solution**:

- The python program iterates through the .txt file to look for a specific keyword
- Once it finds that word, it then stops and iterates backwards from
  that line until it finds a SECOND keyword.
- When the second keyword is found, the program writes the entire line that the keyword
  is on to a new file, and then resumes iterating through the file again from the initial keyword's line.

**Illustration**:

```
<fields>
     <fullName>NAME KEYWORD</fullName> ##line I want to iterate backwards to so I can write it to another file##
     <label>example_label</label>
     <length>131072</length>
     <trackHistory>false</trackHistory> ##line with keyword to stop the iterating process#
     <type>example_type</type>
</fields>
```

Once the line with "NAME KEYWORD" is written to a new file, then the program continues onto the next section, which will have many of the same fields, but a different "NAME KEYWORD", etc.

**Attempted solutions:**
I have been looking for clear information online about how to iterate through a text file in reverse from a given point.  I have found one site, ([kite.com](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-backwards-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20reversed()%20to%20read%20a%20file%20line%20by%20line%20backwards&text=Call%20file.,reverse%20the%20contents%20of%20list%20.)), which illustrates how to use the readlines() and reversed() functions, but those actions are performed on the document as a whole, as opposed to a distinct portion.

I also reviewed [Python's own documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), but the suggestions there do not appear to propose the functionality that I'm looking for here. (Unless I've misunderstanding.)

**TL;DR**
Does anyone have an idea about whether there is an existing module, function or practice which would allow Python to iterate backwards from the middle of a text file?

Comment: This is XML, you should probably use an XML parser. But if the data is originally JSON, why not work on the data from the JSON file directly, rather than convert it to XML first?

Comment: Is the file too big to load into memory? This would be much easier if you had a list of all the lines.

Comment: The only way to go backwards in a file is to use `file.tell()` to save a position, then `file.seek()` to return to that position and read from there.

Comment: @JonSG See the comments in the file, they say which is which.

Comment: `file.tell()` and `file.seek()` are unreliable on Windows text files because of the newline conversion.  If you have XML, as shown here, then use an XML library.  That is the right answer.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille:  Good question; this is how the data is being extracted from the system; the work revolves around Salesforce sandboxes, so we pull data, make our edits, and push it back to the system and check for errors, etc.  I'm just hoping to make it easier to automate a specific part of this process.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in the comments, it would be better to work with the original JSON or use an XML parser. But if these aren't possible (maybe the file is too big to load into memory at once), I think you can do it without having to read in reverse.

```
saved_line = None
for line in oldfile:
    if 'NAME KEYWORD' in line:
        saved_line = line
    elif '<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>' in line and saved_line:
        newfile.write(saved_line)
```

`saved_line` will always contain the same line that you would have found if you iterated backwards after finding the `<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>` line.